# JQuery append child for each span

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code :

```
<div class="truc">
    <span class="test" date-url="12.mp3"></span>
</div>
<div class="truc">
    <span class="test" date-url="64.mp3"></span>
<div>
```

I would like to add inside the span an audio tag with src attribute being the data-url attribute of the span tag.
I wrote the following code:

```
$('span.test').each(function(){
    var ajout = '<audio><source src="'+$(this).attr("data-url")+'"></audio>';
    $(this).append(ajout);
});
```

It works but is not optimized, as append is inside a 'each' loop. I'm struggling to find a better way of writing it. Maybe you could help me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: it should be `data-url` not `date-url` in the attribute.... other than that there is nothing much to do

Comment: That's how you are supposed to do when you have to `append` it on multiple elements. There couldn't be any better way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
// create a single instance of the element(s) you
// wish to append:
var newHTML = $('<audio />', {
    'html' : '<source></source'
}),
// create an unitialised variable to use within 
// within the (inevitable) loop:
    clone;

// select the element(s) to which you wish
// to append new content:
$('span.test').append(function() {

  // create a reference to the cloned element
  // (to avoid recreating the same element(s)
  // every iteration):
  clone = newHTML.clone(true);

  // find the <audio> element within the
  // cloned element, and update its 'src'
  // property; within this loop 'this'
  // refers to the current span.test element
  // over which we're iterating:
  clone.find('audio').prop('src', this.dataset.url);

  // return the cloned, and updated, elements to
  // the append method:
  return clone;
});
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- jQuery:

  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 0):

One tweak you can use is to use append with a callback like, not much of optimization but less verbose

```js
$('span.test').append(function() {
  return '<audio><source src="' + $(this).attr("data-url") + '"></audio>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="truc">
  <span class="test" data-url="12.mp3"></span>
</div>
<div class="truc">
  <span class="test" data-url="64.mp3"></span>
</div>
```